Tuning NonHyperparameters in Scikitlearn
In Scikit Learn RandomSearch or GridSearch , how to include non hyper parameters in the tuning process?! Non hyper parameters are parameters not related to the machine learning algorithms. For example in Time Series problems , the number of lag points to forecast a point forward would be a tunable non hyper parameter.

I think you'll be better off using the Optuna framework. Not only are the available samplers generally more efficient than RandomSearch and Gridsearch, but you can also specify any objective you want.
In order to specify parameters not directly related to the algorithm you'll need to create a custom objective and work your way from there.
